# How to search single keyword from multiple file in perl?

Tags: perl, file, arguments, keyword, perl-module

I have two to three files. In this files path of directories are given. In these file another files are also given. The keyword is given by argument. And these file's name are also given as arguments. So we have to find keyword into all files those are given as argument list. We have to write file name and line inside file that contain keyword.

How to write program of this in Perl?

Comment: Please show us examples of your input files and what output you expect.

Comment: perl task.plx keyword f1.f f2.f
we have to search keyword into f1.f f2.f
and if there are other files mentioned inside f1.f and f2.f
then we have to search into those file also.
the output will generate as.
f1:line that contain keyword.

Comment: Please edit your question. Show what is in file1 (indent the lines with 4 spaces at the start of each line). Show what is in file2. Show what is in file3. Show what you want the result to look like. And explain why that is the result.

Comment: Check the source code of [ack](http://p3rl.org/ack).

Comment: In this files paths of new directories are given.
We have to find keyword in all files presented in those directories.
That path is started with +incdir+path of directory

Comment: ack is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

try this code...instead of giving list of filename as argument,list all files in the file called `file_name.lst` and run this script

```
my $file_name="./file_names.lst";
open(FFILE,$file_name);
while(<FFILE>){
        chomp($_);
        if(-f "$_"){
                $_=~s/ /\\ /g;#escape spaces
                $_=~s/\!/\\\!/g;
                my $myoutput=`grep -in $ARGV[0] "$_"`;
                chomp($myoutput);
             #   print "campaign name is $_ and $myoutput\n";
                        my $errorcode=`echo $?`;
                        chomp( $errorcode);
#                       print "$errorcode\n";
                        if("$errorcode" eq 0 ){
                                print "$_\n";

                        }


        }

}

close(FFILE);
```